# Which kind of literary genre of the following belongs to?

Tags: literature

> 子｛ね｝子｛こ｝子｛のこ｝子｛こ｝子｛ね｝子｛こ｝、 子｛し｝子｛し｝子｛のこ｝子｛こ｝子｛じ｝子｛し｝。

P.S.  It's not necessary limited into one category.  It's somewhat similar to special [*antithetical couplet*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antithetical_couplet) below:

```
種花種,種種種,種種種來種種香; 調琴調,調調調,調調調來調調妙。
```

Comment: What do you mean by "genre"? This is not a literary work like haiku, but [a unique wordplay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ono_no_Takamura#Takamura_in_later_literature) that is hard to categorize further.

Comment: @naruto It's reminiscent of [a tongue twister](https://www.sljfaq.org/afaq/hayakuchi-kotoba.html).

Comment: @ WillihamTotland A useful link, many thanks.

Comment: Wait, ねこのここねこ is not a tongue twister. It's not hard to pronounce at all.

Comment: @naruto Though if the first two on the linked page there qualify then I think it might too.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie It may be equally confusing *visually*, but tongue twister is not defined visually. "Migimimimigimemigimemigimimi" and "Basugasubakuhatsu" are hard to pronounce, but "Neko no ko koneko" is not hard to pronounce at all once you understand its reading. (親亀こけたら and 貴社の記者が are usually not regarded as tongue twisters, either.)

Comment: I know the definition, I just meant to say that OP’s sentence is harder to pronounce than the first two there (for me). Not that it’s particularly challenging though.

Comment: @DariusJahandarie Oh, is that so? バスガス爆発 is one of the most well-known tongue twisters, and I actually practiced it a lot when I was a child. I have never thought or heard ねこのここねこ is a tongue twister.

Answer (score 2):

It's a form of [Constrained writing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constrained_writing), which is any writing that involves artificial constraints to affect its composition (in this case, the use of a single character with multiple readings and meanings).

It bears similarity to the Chinese poem [Lion-Eating Poet in the Stone Den](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lion-Eating_Poet_in_the_Stone_Den) which uses only homophones of "shi", or the English sentence ["Buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo buffalo buffalo Buffalo buffalo"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_buffalo_Buffalo_buffalo).